# Convert String to Object PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am new to PHP. I know there are lot of answers for this. But I can't find a suitable solution for my case. I have a string which looks like this:

```
lo:
00:00:00:00:00:00
enp0s25:
00:21:cc:d4:2a:23
wlp3s0:
84:3a:4b:03:3c:3a
wwp0s20u4:
7a:e3:2a:de:66:09
br-a02a0801833f:
02:42:75:b4:8b:58
docker0:
02:42:cb:f0:5f:0d
```

I want to convert it to a JSON object which needs to be like this.

```
{
 "lo":"00:00:00:00:00:00",
 "enp0s25":"00:21:cc:d4:2a:23",
 "wlp3s0":"84:3a:4b:03:3c:3a",
 "wwp0s20u4":"7a:e3:2a:de:66:09",
 "br-a02a0801833f":"02:42:75:b4:8b:58"
 "docker0":"02:42:cb:f0:5f:0d"
}
```

Help me with some solutions.
Here's the Code:

```
<?php
        $mac = shell_exec("ip link | awk '{print $2}'");
        echo($mac);
        print_r("type:  ");
        print_r(gettype($mac));
        $check = json_decode($mac);
        print_r($check);     
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all) to find all the keys and values in your input string, capturing keys into group 1 and values into group 2. Then you can use [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to put the keys and values together into an associative array, and [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode) that:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z0-9@-]+):\s+((?:[0-9a-f]{2}:){5}[0-9a-f]{2})/i', $str, $matches);
$output = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "lo": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
    "enp0s25": "00:21:cc:d4:2a:23",
    "wlp3s0": "84:3a:4b:03:3c:3a",
    "wwp0s20u4": "7a:e3:2a:de:66:09",
    "br-a02a0801833f": "02:42:75:b4:8b:58",
    "docker0": "02:42:cb:f0:5f:0d"
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SoWKT)

Comment: @NigelRen I could only work with the input data OP provided... but I'll add `@` to the regex for others that find this question. Thanks.

Comment: I think to much effort is put into AI, psychic programming is going to be the next big thing!

Comment: @NigelRen ROTFL! :-)